# How to undo a update statement performed in Oracle 10g iSQLPlus

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a table called car. Accidentally I update values of some columns. No I want to revert back to the previous state. How I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you started a transaction first, you can perform a `ROLLBACK`. If you didn't, you can restore from a backup. If you have neither, you're out of luck. In any case, you should learn to be more careful in the future. :-)

Comment: Another option is flashback; either flashback the entire table or use flashback queries to identify the changes.  But it will only work for as long as there is relevant UNDO information, so it might already be too late.

Comment: I tried to perform a ROLLBACK. But nothing really happened. No changes at all. You mentioned something about transaction. What is it actually. Sorry I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on database size, a restore from backup can be too much. For partial reverts I've found help with export/import (expdp/impdp nowadays) when a logical dump is available. Or use the Oracle Logminer to selectively restore rows to their original setting. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm